# Google Sheets Data entry form that has search functionality and can display matching records I can scroll though

Tags: google-sheets

Ive built this exercise routine creation tool in Google Sheets. I can build the routines from other sheets where I search & select the exercises and then populate my template (the right side of the image below). I've added Save functionality where I can then save all my routines (on the right side of the image) and call them up again to edit individually as needed.

The next step in my project is to be able to search through the existing rows of data on the right (each routine is in one row) by using keywords from the dropdowns at the top. So If I wanted to see all the beginner workouts, I select "Beginner" from the dropdown, and by creating a button called "Search Routines" I will then be able to populate my template with records matching the "Beginner" keyword. I want to be able to scroll through each routine (record) (Next,Previous) until I find a suitable routine for my client, and then print it.

I've been searching for days. Literally. Without luck. Seems like I need to connect my sheet to an external form builder or database that allows you to scroll though records meeting the search criteria. I'd love to be able to build something inside Sheets, however.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HLmN_ukXuWHxUaq4TEVcZG22fAJMMw9ksaIInLGTwao/edit?usp=sharing

Any ideas?

[image: My Workout Routine Database]

Answer (score 0):

try to filter it:

```
=FILTER(H:L; H:H=D1)
```

Comment: Link to copy on sheet added. I want to be able to see matching records, one at a time, populated in the template on the right. When I have scrolled through the populated workouts, and have found the appropriate one, I want to print it in the format that the template is in.